# rosserial_arduino on fuerte

Tags: ros-fuerte, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I installed fuerte yesterday on my Pandaboard, building everything from the source, and all builds find except for rosserial_arduino. It gives me the following compiling error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../rosserial_client/src/rosserial_client/make_library.py", line 583, in <module>
    MakeLibrary(package, path)
  File "../rosserial_client/src/rosserial_client/make_library.py", line 523, in MakeLibrary
    md5sum = roslib.gentools.compute_md5(roslib.gentools.get_file_dependencies(file))
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/roslib/gentools.py", line 275, in get_file_dependencies
    return get_dependencies(spec, package, stdout, stderr)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/roslib/gentools.py", line 318, in get_dependencies
    raise MsgSpecException("Cannot load type %s.  Perhaps the package is missing a dependency."%(str(e)))
roslib.msgs.MsgSpecException: Cannot load type 'geometry_msgs/PoseStamped'.  Perhaps the package is missing a dependency.
```

Other packages that depend on geometry_msgs seem to compile fine, what is wrong with rosserial_arduino that it will fail to compile ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32946/rosserial_arduino-on-fuerte/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2012-04-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-29**:
Does rosserial_arduino declare a dependency on geometry_msgs in its manifest.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is not a direct dependency on geometry_msgs, but the message generation script ([rosserial_client/src/rosserial_clientmake_library.py](https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/trac/browser/rosserial_client/src/rosserial_client/make_library.py)) that creates libraries for messages on the arduino. The script fails on geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.

This issue is described in greater detail in this [ticket](https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/trac/ticket/56), and a patch is attached to the ticket.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2012-04-30**:
Thank you very much!

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-04-30**:
@piyushk: With the attached patch, how one should proceed with the fiix? I never have experience using patch, is it the one ".diff", BTW, how to use it?

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-04-30**:
You can read more about apply patches at http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appy-patch-file-using-patch-command/ You need to run "roscd rosserial" and then "patch -p1 < /path/to/patch-file"

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-04-30**:
@piyushk: That's great..Thanks a lot..